# bash shell scripting: How to group argument list into N items?

Tags: bash, shell

The use case here is I want to take a set of files such as `*` and build arglists with them in a loop, `N` at a time. For example,

```
$ ls 
a.jpg
b.jpg
v.jpg
z.jpg
123.jpg
1234.jpg
```

`N` here is two, I want to run e.g. `command a.jpg b.jpg`, `command v.jpg, z.jpg`, etc.

How can I do it?

```
for file in *; do
    command [???]
done
```

It doesn't have to make use of a for loop. Hopefully there is a UNIX utility that I don't know about yet which is able to re-arrange the arg list a bit. Or perhaps I gotta do something fancy with `tr` and `IFS`.

Here's how I can do this if my files are predictably named with numbers, or if I just wanted to use numbers rather than operate on glob-expanded files (this example has `N` = 3):

```
for number in {0..10..3}; do
    echo $number $((number + 1)) $((number + 2))
done
```

this yields...

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
9 10 11
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See `xargs` and its `-n` option.

```
ls | xargs -n3 command
```

If your file names contain whitespace, you might need the `-0` option and `find` with `-print0` to list the files.

Comment: I was writing this when I noticed "a new answer…" - You beat me to it.

Comment: I knew this. Why did I forget that `xargs` could do this? `xargs` can even parallelize scripts. Super freaking useful for my imagemagick scripts as well.

Comment: @StevenLu This won't work with spaces in filenames, but maybe that's not an issue in your specific case. See my answer for an alternative without `xargs`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a bash array:

```
files=(*)
for number in $(seq 0 3 $((${#arr[@]}-1)) ); do
    echo "${files[number]}" "${files[number+1]}" "${files[number+2]}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty clean way in pure `bash`, without `xargs`, and proper handling of spaces in filenames:

```
set -- *
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    file1="$1"; shift
    file2="$1"; shift
    # ./do_something "$file1" "$file2"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with a manual straight forward string accumulation approach. Something like this.

I am making imagemagick scripts.

```
i=0
targdir=$2
accum=
for image in $(ls $1); do
    accum="$accum $image"
    if [[ $((i % 2)) -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo testing $accum
        accum=
    fi
    ((i ++))
done
```